# How change mp3 tag and photos with PHP?

Tags: php, tags, mp3, photo

How change MP3 photo with php ?

I use id3_get

But in demos not found change photo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some previous SO answers:

[How can I extract the album art from an MP3 ID3 tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746647/how-can-i-extract-the-album-art-from-an-mp3-id3-tag)

[setting album art of a mp3 with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114357/setting-album-art-of-a-mp3-with-php)

[Get album art from MP3 PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145507/get-album-art-from-mp3-php)

[Get cover art from mp3 files through PHP and display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046182/get-cover-art-from-mp3-files-through-php-and-display-it)

Look at the last link, especially.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I use composer.

```
composer require james-heinrich/getid3
```

index.php file

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$getID3 = new getID3;

$tagwriter                      = new getid3_writetags;
$tagwriter->filename            = './music.mp3';
$tagwriter->tagformats          = array('id3v1','id3v2.3');
$tagwriter->overwrite_tags      = true;
$tagwriter->remove_other_tags   = true;
$tagwriter->tag_encoding        = 'UTF-8';
$pictureFile = file_get_contents("logo.png");

$TagData = array(
    'title'             => array('My Title'),
    'artist'            => array('My Artist'),
    'attached_picture'  => array(
        array (
            'data'          => $pictureFile,
            'picturetypeid' => 3,
            'mime'          => 'image/png',
            'description'   => 'My Picture'
        )
    )
);

$tagwriter->tag_data = $TagData;

if ($tagwriter->WriteTags()){
    return true;
}else{
    throw new \Exception(implode(' : ', $tagwriter->errors));
}
?>
```